# Cookbook not found with vagrant, berkshelf and chef-solo

Tags: vagrant, chef-solo

I'm attempting to get a vagrant instance up and running, but when I do `vagrant up --provision`, it fails with the error:

```
ERROR: Cookbook postgres not found.
```

I'm using `vagrant-berkshelf`, which appears to be copying the cookbooks across. That is: when I `vagrant ssh` to the VM, I can see a cookbook `/tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/postgres`.

So why isn't chef (inside the vagrant box) finding the cookbook? I thought that the `vagrant-berkshelf` plugin was supposed to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an internally created postgres cookbook or not, but I would verify that the metadata.rb of the postgres cookbook you have is properly named. At the very least, it should have

```
name 'postgres'
```